# Having class X, how to pass X as a template argument to itself?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, macros, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a Red-Black Tree that inherits from a BS Tree. `BST` uses `BSNode` as its nodes while `RBT` (Red-Black Tree) uses `RBNode` which in turn inherits from `BSNode`. The code looks like this, the problems arise in the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define _BST BST<K, T, RBNode<K, T>>

// attempt 1
//template <typename K, typename T, typename NODE>
//class BSNode
//{
//
//public:
//
//  K key;
//  T value;
//
//  NODE* left;
//  NODE* right;
//
//  // ...
//};

// attempt 2
template <typename K, typename T, template<typename, typename> typename NODE>
class BSNode
{

public:

    K key;
    T value;

    NODE<K, T>* left;
    NODE<K, T>* right;

    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T>
class RBNode : public BSNode<K, T, RBNode>
{

public:

    bool color;

    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T, typename NODE>
class BST
{

public:

    NODE* root = nullptr;

    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T>
class RBT : public _BST
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    RBT<int, int> rbt;

    // attempt 1
    // recursive and can't be done.
    // BST<int, int, BSNode<int, int, BSNode<int, int, BSNode<int.....

    // attempt 2
    // template arguments list for NODE takes
    // 2 arguments while BSNode takes 3. Not compatible.
    // BST<int, int, BSNode<int, int, BSNode>>
}
```

questions:

1 -
how to implement it so that `BST`s are just written as `BST<int, int>` while still having it accept different types of nodes for left and right such as `RBNode`?

2 -
how to let `RBNode` inherit from `BSNode` while being able to create BSTs and `RBT`s?

3 -
in attempt 2, in the macro `#define _BST BST<K, T, RBNode<K, T>>`, why do I get an error when writing it as `#define _BST BST<K, T, RBNode>`? in the class `BSNode`, left and right are defined
as `NODE<K, T>*`. this means substituting `NODE` by `BSNode<K, T>` would result in left and
right being equal to `BSNode<K, T><K, T>*`. why is this the right way?

Is there something wrong with the design or if can it be improved?

Comment: I am afraid you're missing an additional level of indirection. The idiomatic way is to use a CRTP I think.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you give an example?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp `RBNode` should be passed as a class type deriving from `BST`.

Comment: The problem with the title is that `X` is either a class or a class template. Unrelated: `_BST`  is a name that's reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate both `Node` and `Tree` from the specific `BSNode`, `RBNode`, `BSTree` and `RBTree` types

```
template <typename K, typename T, template<typename, typename> typename NODE>
struct Node
{
    K key;
    T value;

    NODE<K, T>* left;
    NODE<K, T>* right;

    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T>
struct BSNode : Node<K, T, BSNode>
{};

template <typename K, typename T>
struct RBNode : Node<K, T, RBNode>
{
    bool color;

    // ...
};

template <typename NODE>
struct Tree
{
    NODE* root = nullptr;

    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T>
struct BSTree : Tree<BSNode<K, T>>
{
    // ...
};

template <typename K, typename T>
struct RBTree : Tree<RBNode<K, T>>
{
    // ...
};
```

Aside: if you are making everything `public`, you may as well use `struct` over `class`. The only difference is `public` by default.

Comment: Well, I've thought of this way but I'm not sure would this be a good solution or not.. now instead of BSNode being a parent for RBNode, they are siblings and an RBNode can't be substituted  in place of BSNode. Also, I'd be thankful if you're able to provide an answer for question 3. Thanks!

Comment: @StackExchange123 they aren't the same type, so it's good that you can't mix them. #3 is because you define `NODE` as a type, not a template. Nowhere in `BST` do you write `NODE<K, T>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe RBNode is just a BSNode with the boolean color added to it. Why you're saying that they're not the same type?

Comment: because you shoudn't put an `RBNode` in a `BSTree`

Comment: You can still write functions that don't care if you pass a `BSTree` or a `RBTree` without inheritance

Answer (score 1):

The issue resides in node definitions. For simplicity it would be better using node as tree itself and therefore removing BST and RBT classes.

The node classes could be defined as:

```
template <typename K, typename T, template<typename, typename> typename Node>
class GenericNode
{

public:
    K key;
    T value;

    Node<K, T>* left = nullptr;
    Node<K, T>* right = nullptr;

    // common code
};

template <typename K, typename T>
class BSNode : public GenericNode<K, T, BSNode>
{
    // specific code if exists
};

template <typename K, typename T>
class RBNode : public GenericNode<K, T, RBNode>
{

public:
    bool color;

    // specific code
};

int main()
{
    {
        BSNode<int, float> n1, n2, n3;
        n1.left = &n2;
        n1.right = &n3;
    }

    {
        RBNode<int, float> n1, n2, n3;
        n1.left = &n2;
        n1.right = &n3;
        n1.color = true;
    }
}
```

Reply 3. NODE<T,K>, as template parameter of BSNode class, allows using pointers to derived classes. Otherwise, BSNode can used for left and right pointers but it may be necessary making static casts to derived classes (eg. static_cast<RBNode*>(left)) in many cases. This is the reason using NODE<T,K>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not answer question 3, plus, trees and nodes are different things. For example, trees will contain the root node while nodes don't.

Comment: I added reply 3. What are the main differences between tree node and tree? A "std::unique_ptr<RBNode> my_tree" could be a perfectly defined tree. It depends how node details are exposed. IMO the node should expose methods and not raw fields.

Comment: Well, in Red Black trees for example, roots have special conditions for them. For example, if the root is red, it can be changed to black with no problem. this applies only to the root. Also, if the tree is empty, that means that the root is null, but the tree isn't null yet. I want to be able to use the tree and empty it up and fill it again with having no problem and for that I would need a wrapper for the nodes (the trees). As of for the question 3, I'm not quite sure what do you mean. I've updated the question so that it's  more clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. About reply 3, Node struct can have only K and T parameters and left and right pointers to Node and it works. Then deriving from Node, you will still have pointers to Node (not pointers to descendant classes). For accessing derived objects (eg. RBNode) from left and right members, static casts would be needed.